# <ul> fit parent <li> width

Tags: html, css

I would like my nested `<ul id='child'>` to fit parent `<il id='parent'>` **width**.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li id='parent'>
  <a href='#' id='setter'>$variable</a>
  <ul id='child'>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
  </ul>   
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#setter {padding:0 15px; display:inline-block} /*as menu item*/
#child {...?}
```

The problem is that link is setting the `<li>` width since the link text is changeable variable. With other words, `<li>` width cannot be fixed.

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle showing your problem?

Comment: If not overwritten, what you're trying to achieve is the default behaviour of those elements.

Comment: @Zenith I want blue bar to be as long as red. Without fixed widths.
http://jsfiddle.net/G3TBn/

Comment: @BikerJohn add [`display: block`](http://jsfiddle.net/3zmDW/) to `#setter`. Though mind that this has actually nothing to do with nested ul/li elements. Also `li` don't need `display: block` in this case.

Comment: @Yoshi cant do that, forgot to mention that #setter already has display:inline-block property since it is part of menu.

Comment: @BikerJohn Then maybe try `width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;` http://jsfiddle.net/3zmDW/1/   But have a look at `box-sizing` compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `float` the `<li>`:

```css
#parent
{
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G3TBn/4/

But then, if the content in `#child` grows wider than `#setter`, the width of the `<li>` will grow as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/G3TBn/5/

In that case, you could then position `#child` absolutely:

```css
#parent
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#child
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G3TBn/6/

But, then that can cause layout flow issues (which may or may not be an issue):

http://jsfiddle.net/G3TBn/7/

You can set a fixed width at runtime (as opposed to design time) with JavaScript.  Measure the inline element whose width you want to use, and set that as the fixed width of the parent element.

```
document.getElementById("parent").style.width = 
    document.getElementById("setter").offsetWidth + "px";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G3TBn/2/

Comment: If I'm reading the question properly, this is a standard CSS issue.

Comment: @ralph.m - Maybe my original answer was a bit hasty.  There *may* be some acceptable pure CSS approaches (see my edits), depending on your needs.  CSS does not provide a means of constraining the size of one element based on the content size of a sibling element.

Comment: Indeed, yeah. I read the question as asking how the child can fill the width of the parent.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is

```
#child {margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

and maybe width: 100% if you've set a different width elsewhere.

Also, it's `<li>` ("List Item"), not `<il>`. :-)

EDIT: If this is a drop down list, you need to wrap the `<a>` around the sub ` anyway. Here's a better way to go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

ul {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#setter {background: red; display: block;}
#child {background: blue;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li id='parent'>
          <a href='#' id='setter'>$variable
          <ul id='child'>
                <li>one</li>
                <li>two</li>
          </ul>
          </a>   
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your example, the child LIs ARE the same width as the parent. If you put a background color on the parent, you'll see that. The red background is on the `<a>` element, which is inline, so it doesn't fill the whole space.

Comment: I've updated my post with an example that does what you want and fixes your code, too, as there is an error in it (assuming this is a drop down menu).

Comment: Cant get it to work. Can you try to apply your solution in jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/G3TBn/3/

Comment: This is the code I posted above in a live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uACko It defaults to 100% width until you place it in an outer container with a lesser width. You also didn't fix the problem in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I would do so:

```
#setter {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    background:yellow;
    padding:0 15px;
}
#child {
    position:absolute;
    background:red;
    width:inherit;
}
```

might have to adjust padding. but I hope you get the idea.

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/NQKgu/)